# Linq to object freezing

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have some LINQ to Object Query Code:

```
List<ePayDocumentOperation> additionalDocuments = new List<ePayDocumentOperation>();
try
{
    additionalDocuments = (from op in possibleClientDocuments
                           let senderAccountID = GetSenderAccountID(con, op)
                           where Filter.Wallets.Contains(senderAccountID)
                           select op).ToList();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // some catcher
}
```

**possibleClientDocuments** object contains about 3 000 records. Not so much but the query freeze and I don't get result. I don't get any execeptions. I try to select code to try catch block but I don't see any exceptions and at the same time I don't get result too.

How to check the problem of query and why I don't getting result?

Thanks!

P.S.

```
private static long GetSenderAccountID(LavaPayEntities Con, ePayDocumentOperation operation)
        {
            long result = default(long);
            // Payment
            if (operation.OperationPatternID == Chart.Operations.PS_Payment)
            {
                var ipnRequest = Con.eIPNRequests.FirstOrDefault(ir => ir.OperationID == operation.ID);
                if (ipnRequest == null) return result;
                if (ipnRequest.ClientAccountID != null && ipnRequest.ClientAccountID != 0) return (long)ipnRequest.ClientAccountID;
                var clientAccount = Con.eAccounts.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Email.Email == ipnRequest.ClientEmail);
                if (clientAccount != null)
                {
                    result = clientAccount.ID;
                }
                else
                {
                    var client = ipnRequest.Client;
                    if (client != null)
                    {
                        clientAccount = client.Accounts.FirstOrDefault();
                        if (clientAccount != null)
                        {
                            result = clientAccount.ID;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // Other Operations
            else
            {
                result = operation.SenderAccountID.HasValue ? operation.SenderAccountID.Value : 0;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you convert it to `foreach` style to see if it works this way?

Comment: Have you tried with a specific AccountID yet instead of the GetSenderAccountID method? Perhaps something in that method causes the issue?

Comment: How long does `GetSenderAccountID(con, op)` take per item?  Is it making a connection to the database?  Can there be a lock in that method that is blocking and you somehow got yourself into a deadlock?  I bit more information about GetSenderAccountID can help here.

Comment: @IllidanS4 It's good idea. I don't know why I don't tried it. Thanks! :)

Comment: @IllidanS4 switching to `foreach` would make it easier to debug, but is unlikely to make it behave differently.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch Yes, GetSenderAccountID have connection I pass it as first param to the methed. Then in the method using this connection I connect to database to get data. I have updated the question with adding the method GetSenderAccountID

Comment: Looking at GetSenderAccountID you will likely send at least 3 queries to the database for each invocation of the method. Times 3000 objects we are talking about 9000 queries.

To speed that up you should perhaps prefetch all the required SenderAccountIDs into a Dictionary or something similar and access them using a key derived from your operation.

Comment: Queries are always non-trivial.  Some databases have strange behavior with locking if you do or don't have a transaction open for the whole query.    Any reason you can't stash the `SenderAccountID` in `op` and just use that value directly?